# Lucene Score results

Tags: search, lucene

In Lucene if you had multiple indexes that covered only one partition each. Why does the same search on different indexes return results with different scores? The results from different servers match exactly.

i.e. if I searched for :

- Name - John Smith
- DOB - 11/11/1934

**Partition 0** would return a score of 0.345

**Partition 1** would return a score of 0.337

Both match exactly on name and DOB.

Answer (score 20):

The [scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) contains the Inverse Document Frequency(IDF). If the term "John Smith" is in one partition, 0, 100 times and in partition 1, once. The score for searching for John Smith would be higher search in partition 1 as the term is more scarce.

To get round this you would wither have to have your index being over all partitions, or you would need to override the IDF.

Comment: Or you could construct a multisearcher from all indices.

Answer (score 13):

Because the score is determined on the index if I am not completely mistaken.

If you have different indexes (more/less or different data that was indexed), the score will differ:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/scoring.html

(Warning: Contains Math :-))

Answer (score 9):

You may also be interested in the output of the [`explain()` method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)), and the resulting [`Explanation` object](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Explanation.html), which will give you an idea of how things are scored the way they are.